# not fully grasping why i'd have an interface in a class, rather than inherit from it

Tags: c#, interface

I'm looking over the SOLID principles and came across some bits of code for SRP.

I have this code, but I do not have a clue why I'd have an interface, declared in the way that I do below? What good does this do to me? I found [here](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/solid-principles-in-c-an-overview.htm), it shows a solution, but it doesn't really explain how the code works better or why things are the way they are.

The thing I don't understand is:

`IGateUtility _gateUtility;` In `public class ServiceStation`, and right below it is the constructor with `IGateUtility` as parameter. Why is this written like that? What's the parameter I would have to pass.

```
public class ServiceStation
{
    IGateUtility _gateUtility;

    public ServiceStation(IGateUtility gateUtility)
    {
        this._gateUtility = gateUtility;
    }
    public void OpenForService()
    {
        _gateUtility.OpenGate();
    }

    public void DoService()
    {
        //Check if service station is opened and then
        //complete the vehicle service
    }

    public void CloseForDay()
    {
        _gateUtility.CloseGate();
    }
}

public class ServiceStationUtility : IGateUtility
{
    public void OpenGate()
    {
        //Open the shop if the time is later than 9 AM
    }

    public void CloseGate()
    {
        //Close the shop if the time has crossed 6PM
    }
}


public interface IGateUtility
{
    void OpenGate();

    void CloseGate();
}
```

Comment: It's for dependency injection. The idea being that you'll want to test your `ServiceStation` class without necessarily using an actual `ServiceStationUtility` instance, but instead with a different `IGateUtility` implementation, perhaps one that's a "fake" version that returns contrived test data.

Comment: It's another layer of abstraction.  That's a very simple example

Comment: It is in costructor so that it can be injected to this class. You can pass any class that implements IGateUtility. This so flexible and example of coding to interface not implementation

Comment: This is the difference between "is-a" and "has-a".

Comment: Code to an interface, not an implementation.

Comment: The comments in the ServiceStationUtility class seem to be misleading; if the service station tells the gate to open it should just do so, not based on a timer or other conditional (that logic would usually reside in the service station)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor parameter is an example of **dependency injection**, specifically the technique known as "constructor injection" (which is usually the preferred technique).

The `ServiceStation` isn't supposed to contain the logic of a `IGateUtility` because it doesn't have anything to do with the gate (Single Responsibility Principle). It does need to *use* the gate however so you pass an object implementing `IGateUtility` in.

Generally speaking I don't think inheritance would make sense in this instance regardless; but there is a principle that states:

> Prefer Composition to Inheritance

Which basically means; inject (compose) objects to gain access to their behavior instead of inheriting from them.

Answer (score 2):

There are few steps before we reach to the class that you currently have.

### Step 1

`ServiceStation` is tightly couple to `ServiceStationUtility`. As the result, we could not unit-test `ServiceStation`.

```
public class ServiceStation
{
    ServiceStationUtility _gateUtility;

    public ServiceStation()
    {
        this._gateUtility = new ServiceStationUtility();
    }

    public void OpenForService()
    {
        _gateUtility.OpenGate();
    }

    public void DoService() 
   {
   }

    public void CloseForDay()
    {
        _gateUtility.CloseGate();
    }
}
```

### Step 2

We inject the dependencies via `construction injection pattern`, and we could somehow manage to implement unit-tests, but `ServiceStation` is still tightly coupled to `ServiceStationUtility`.

```
public class ServiceStation
{
    ServiceStationUtility _gateUtility;

    public ServiceStation(ServiceStationUtility gateUtility)
    {
        this._gateUtility = gateUtility;
    }

    public void OpenForService()
    {
        _gateUtility.OpenGate();
    }

    public void DoService()
    {
        //Check if service station is opened and then
        //complete the vehicle service
    }

    public void CloseForDay()
    {
        _gateUtility.CloseGate();
    }
}
```

### Step 3

> **Liskov's Substitution Principle** - Subclass should be interchangeable
>   with superclass.
>
> **Dependency Inversion Principle** - High-level components should not
>   dependent on low-level components, or should not be responsible for
>   creating them. Instead, they should depend on the abstraction that
>   provided to them.

Then finally what you have. It basically satisfies SO_ID principles; Liskov's Substitution Principle is not required to satisfy in this case.

```
public class ServiceStation
{
    IGateUtility _gateUtility;

    public ServiceStation(IGateUtility gateUtility)
    {
        this._gateUtility = gateUtility;
    }

    public void OpenForService()
    {
        _gateUtility.OpenGate();
    }

    public void DoService()
    {
        //Check if service station is opened and then
        //complete the vehicle service
    }

    public void CloseForDay()
    {
        _gateUtility.CloseGate();
    }
}

public interface IGateUtility
{
    void OpenGate();

    void CloseGate();
}
```

### Sample Unit Tests

A class that depends on an interface does not depend on anything further. That abstraction enables loose coupling and allows us to implement unit-tests easily.

```
using Moq;
using Xunit;

public class ServiceStationTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void OpenForService_should_call_OpenGate_once()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockGateUtility = new Mock<IGateUtility>();
        mockGateUtility.Setup(x => x.OpenGate());

        // Act
        var sut = new ServiceStation(mockGateUtility.Object);
        sut.OpenForService();

        // Assert
        mockGateUtility.Verify(x => x.OpenGate(), Times.Once);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CloseForDay_should_call_CloseGate_once()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockGateUtility = new Mock<IGateUtility>();
        mockGateUtility.Setup(x => x.CloseGate());

        // Act
        var sut = new ServiceStation(mockGateUtility.Object);
        sut.CloseForDay();

        // Assert
        mockGateUtility.Verify(x => x.CloseGate(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SRP stands for **Single Responsibility Principle** . So Here **Service Class**  don't have any responsibility to create the **ServiceStationUtility** object.

Let's understand it with an example. suppose you are not using any interface, then your code look like the following.

```
    public class ServiceStation
    {
      ServiceStationUtility  _gateUtility;

    public ServiceStation()
    {
        this._gateUtility = new ServiceStationUtility();
    }
    public void OpenForService()
    {
        _gateUtility.OpenGate();
    }

    public void DoService()
    {
        //Check if service station is opened and then
        //complete the vehicle service
    }

    public void CloseForDay()
    {
        _gateUtility.CloseGate();
    }
     }

   public class ServiceStationUtility 
   {
       public void OpenGate()
       {
        //Open the shop if the time is later than 9 AM
       }

      public void CloseGate()
      {
        //Close the shop if the time has crossed 6PM
      }
    }
```

So without using the interface now Service Station class is also responsible for creating the  **ServiceStation** objects , which is the violation of **SRP**.

**Second Problem**

With above code is that if you want to provide different implementation for **OpenGate()** and **CloseGate()** . you have to create another class. Due to which you have to change the code in **ServiceStation** class again.

**Reason To Use Interface**

Interfaces allow dependency injection. that means task of object creation is delegated to the third party. that means here **ServiceClass** don't need to know who is actual provider of the object . **ServiceClass** just follow 
 here interface. Same for **ServiceStationUtility**  class , this class also don't know who is going to use it.

So interfaces help in building  **Loosely Coupled Architecture**